# Checking whether alphabets has appeared at least once

Tags: python

Here's this program, where I have to implement a function that will check whether all the alphabets from a to j (converting all the alphabets to lowercase) has appeared at least once in the given string or not. If all of these alphabets (a to j) appear at least once, then the result will be 5. If any one of the alphabets (a to j) is not in the given string, then the result will be 6. Finally, have to return this result and print the statement, "Chelsea is the best club in England" that many times.

**If I call:**
`A black jackal is hunting a full grown deer`

**The output should be:**

```
Chelsea is the best club in England
Chelsea is the best club in England
Chelsea is the best club in England
Chelsea is the best club in England
Chelsea is the best club in England
```

**I tried:**

```
output = "Chelsea is the best club in England"
user_string = input("Enter the string: ")

def alphabets(string):
    lower_string = user_string.lower()
    for alph in lower_string: 
        if alph >= 'a' and alph <= 'j' in user_string:
            result = 5
            return (output * 5)
        else:
            result = 6
            return (output * 6)
    return result

print(alphabets("ABBCDEFEFGHI"))
```

**Output came everything in a line:**

```
Enter the string: ABBCDEFEFGHI
Chelsea is the best club in EnglandChelsea is the best club in EnglandChelsea is the best club in EnglandChelsea is the best club in EnglandChelsea is the best club in EnglandChelsea is the best club in England
```

***What should I do to get these 5 sentences in 5 lines?***

Comment: Why doesn't the function use the `string` parameter?

Comment: `if alph >= 'a' and alph <= 'j' in user_string` makes no sense.

Comment: Your title says the question is about checking whether the all the letters appear. But the question says the problem is just returning multiple strings with newlines between them.

Comment: You should really debug your code - it is weird in so many ways...

Comment: It seems you accepted an answer that totally doesn't answer your post correctly

Comment: `if len(set("abcdefghij").intersection(user_string.lower())) ==len("abcdefghij")`: print it 5 times, else 6 times. or better:`set.issubset()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a newline to your variable output .

```
 output = "Chelsea is the best club in England \n "
```

Alternatively, your return statement could also have a newline

```
if alph >= 'a' and alph <= 'j' in user_string:
            result = 5
            return ((output + "\n") * 5)

        else:
            result = 6
            return ((output + "\n") * 6)
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can get only the unique characters of a string using:

```
''.join(set(MyString))
```

e.g.

```
''.join(set("a black jackal is hunting a full grown deer"))
```

gives:

```
'nohbajesrilcwdkuftg'
```

Obviously pass it through the lower case function first

*EDIT* sorry I didn't fully read the question I was more concerned with your implementation of the counting.

You can output something N times on different lines using:

```
a_string = "abc"
for line in range(N-1):
  
  print(a_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you need to verify all from `a` to `j` you can't return something directly, you need to iterate all the string. You just need to iterate over all chars from `a` to `j`, if one is missing in the words, case `5`, at the end case `6` because you'd have found all chars

```
def alphabets(string):
    lower_string = string.lower()
    for c in 'abcdefghij':  
        if c not in lower_string:
            return "\n".join(5 * [output])
    return "\n".join(6 * [output])
```

But the  **simplest** you can do so far is

```
def alphabet(string):
    count = 6 if set("abcdefghij").issubset(string.lower()) else 5
    return "\n".join(count * [output])
```

Comment: ... `if set("abcdefghij").issubset(string.lower()):` ...  would to that as well

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

You never actually pass `user_string` to `alphabet`, instead you pass a hardcoded string literal. In `alphabet`, you don't even use the `string` parameter. Instead, you rely on the existence of `user_string` from the outer scope.

To print the five or six strings on separate lines, you can either `str.join` a list of strings with a newline character, like so:

```
def alphabet(string):
    message = "Chelsea is the best club in England"
    count = [6, 5][all(char in string.lower() for char in "abcdefghij")]
    print("\n".join([message] * count))


user_string = input("Enter the string: ")
alphabet(user_string)
```

... Or include a newline as part of each line, and then "multiply" the message string five or six times - in this case you'll want to set `print`'s optional `end` parameter to an empty string, as I've done below.

```
def alphabet(string):
    message = "Chelsea is the best club in England\n"
    count = [6, 5][all(char in string.lower() for char in "abcdefghij")]
    print(message * count, end="")
```

You could also splat/unpack a list of messages, and set `print`'s optional `sep` parameter to a newline:

```
def alphabet(string):
    message = "Chelsea is the best club in England"
    count = [6, 5][all(char in string.lower() for char in "abcdefghij")]
    print(*[message] * count, sep="\n")
```

Comment: That lacks of explanation, and is kind of tricky for a new user

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that by `alphabet` you mean `letter`. Given that, the code should look something like this:

```
letters_needed = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
output = "Chelsea is the best club in England"
user_string = input("Enter the string: ")

def alphabets(string):
    lower_string = user_string.lower()
    for letter in letters_needed:
        if lower_string.count(letter) == 0:
            return 6
    return 5

print((output+"\n") * alphabets("ABBCDEFEFGHI"))
```

#### Explanation

In the `for loop` we go through each letter in the `letters_needed` list. If one `letter` does not appear in the `lower_string`, we return 6. If the loop exits, meaning no value has been returned, it means that every letter in the letters_needed list appears more than once in the `lower_string` therefore we can return 5. Lastly we print the desired string, adding a newline `\n` in the end, the amount of times returned by the `alphabets` function.